# can use where in sql server to find bigger word in smaller word

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a table that have a column like these :(table1)

```
1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1-2001   
1-GM-100-20013-F01-N-1-01
1-GM-100-20050-F01-N-1-1001
```

And another table with these rows(table2)

```
1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1
1-GM-100-20013-F01-N-1
1-GM-100-20050-F01-N-1
```

As you can see i can use `where` on table 2 row  to find the rows that similar to table 1 values use `like statement` but i need somethnig vise versa ,I need to find the rows inside table1 that some part of them are inside table1 for example

```
select * from table2 where table1Column contains table2 ???
```

For example  when i  pass   `1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1-2001` this to my query from table1 and i expect my query to return `this  1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1`

Comment: How you are comparing 1st row of both the tables?? INNER JOIN??

Comment: `table1.col LIKE table2.col + '%'`

Comment: This type of like not support, bigger word can't finds in smaller word

Comment: why you want to return this..1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1

Comment: @EhsanAkbar, Better than selecting `1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1` from other table, you can make a substring of `1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1-2001` to get the desired result.

Comment: Does every record begin with `1-GM-100-20003-F01-N-1`?  If not, then do all prefixes have the same length?  Can you update your sample data so that we might be able to come up a rule?

Comment: @TheGameiswar it is a example i just need to search bigger word in smaller word

Comment: @JibinBalachandran I can't because my rows in table 2 don't have a specific format

Comment: bigger word in smaller word not possible

Comment: @SandipPatel thank you ,i think your solution is the main answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of like not support, bigger word can't finds in smaller word.

SQL like works to find some part of word from bigger word

Answer (score 0):

If these values have a fixed length (if I've counted good this is a 22 length, you can use the substring method in sql server to get a partial of your text

```
select tbl2.*
from table2 tbl2
//... other stuff
where tbl2.table2column LIKE SUBSTRING(tbl1.column,0,22)
```

Syntax and usage of SUBSTRING method:

> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

Comment: I said that my values in table 1 doesn't have a specific format

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Then you need to update your question and let us know what sort of structure we can expect.

Comment: Indeed, you should provide me more info so I can refactor my query.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * form table where column like 'Your Conditions'
```